# Easiest way to integrate captcha's into Symfony2 FOSUserBundle registration?

Tags: symfony, captcha, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony2 and the FOSUserBundle to manage registration and logins. I'd like to add a captcha system. Is there are pre-existing bundle or tutorial on this?

Of course, I could try to roll my own using Google re-captcha. In that case, is Google reCaptcha a good choice, or should I use some other API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are indeed a bundles for that, take a look at:

[CaptchaBundle](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle)

Or

[EWZRecaptchaBundle](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle)

Both got (most likely) all the documentation you need added in the README.md file or extended documentation.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I don't suppose you would know how best to attach them to an existing FOSUserBundle installation? Since I previously set up an invite system, I have overridden Form\UserType, Form\Registration, RegistrationController, etc.

Comment: If you already overridden those that would only make it easier to add the captcha. Before I explain the total documentation you should read both of them and select the one you like most.

Comment: The CaptchaBundle documentation says the only usage is $builder->add('captcha', 'captcha');  . Do I really need to do nothing else (besides install it of course)? I come from old PHP land where I would need to modify the form PHP, the receiving PHP, and perhaps make an API call in the process to a 3rd party captcha API. =x

Comment: The nice thing about new PHP land is that in most frameworks alot of stuff is done for you. I suppose you use the formbuilder symfony provides, if so it should be as easy as the documentation says. There is no need of a 3rd party captcha API because the bundle generates the images it self and validates the input. I recommend you to just try it, if it doesn't work like you want it to you only have to remove like 5 rules.

Comment: If you run in to any problems just tell me i will gladly assist you further.

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you. I spent 2 hours dealing with some issues upgrading composer.phar and vendor libraries. I have a few things to do but I'll be back in an hour

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19115/discussion-between-arcymag-and-matsrietdijk)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a tiny bundle called [caitcha-bundle](https://github.com/mktcode/caitcha-bundle).

According to this part of the [fos user bundle documenation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) implementation should be quite easy because you only have to activate the caitcha bundle and add `$builder->add('caitcha', 'caitcha');` to the form type.

Because captcha images and any other approaches that require some user interaction which is not related to the form itself are very annoying in my optinion, I tried to implement an invisible bot protection by using the honeypot method and a check for the time it took to fill in the form. It works well for my use cases but still has to be extended by more checks I suppose. I would appreciate any suggestions to improve this bundle.