# FOSUser bundle: Is it possible to stop user registration inside REGISTRATION_SUCCESS or REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE events?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am implementing recaptcha with fosuserbundle.

Is it possible to stop user registration or password reset with an error message through event listeners?

Or should I just override the controllers?

I would prefer to avoid using a third bundle to integrate recaptcha

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238348/easiest-way-to-integrate-captchas-into-symfony2-fosuserbundle-registration

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing similar with that question.
I specifically ask about stopping the flow through the events and specifically say that I do not want to use a third party bundle.

Comment: Well i guess i would first create a listener from the REGISTRATION_COMPLETED and try your own captacha field, if it's false, then i would dispatch a failure event REGISTRATION_FAILURE. Did you try playing with this event ?

Comment: Or you can simply override your registerFunction : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/730a8a5f6633ae913a838d26b1c7156faa6ed697/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.rst

Comment: Yes, I I tried throwing various exceptions and/or dispatching a failure event, but the user either kept getting saved to the database, or the process died by the exception. I do not remember if I tried to dispatch a failure on the INITIALIZE event though. I will try it later today.
I guess working with the form builder makes some more sense.
Overriding the controller does not feel such a good practice because you are basically cutting yourself from potential patches to the bundle and adding to your technical debt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registration_success occure just after sucessful submitting and perform the result in database so, just before performing you can send a httresponse (inside the response event) that provide redirection (or otherelse)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried a redirection but it did not work

Comment: use set response and after if response is set do not persist and then return response